# Loop in a dictionary

Tags: python, string, loops, dictionary

I need do write str from a dictionary and do it like this:

```
s = '\n'.join('\t'.join(key, sectionResults[key]) for key in sectionResults)
```

But there is an error:

```
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not dict
```

How to fix it? Thanks

Comment: It sounds like `sectionResults` is not the dictionary you think it is. Rather, it's a list of dictionaries. So `key` is a single dictionary and you're trying to use it to index the list.

Comment: Post an example of `sectionResults`

Answer (score 0):

```
joined_dicts = reduce(lambda p, v: p + v, [[t,y] for t, y in [z.items() for z in sectionResults]])

s = '\n'.join(str(x) + '\t' + str(y) for x, y in joined_dicts)
```

Comment: Clearly `sectionResult` is a list (see the error message), which I don’t suppose lists have the `items` method

Comment: The op thinks it is but it’s a list

Comment: Yes, there is no 'item' method

Comment: `list indices` implies that `sectionResult` is a list and that the `key` is a dict.

Comment: Yes, correct, abccd. I see that now. I was just answering the question that was asked.

Comment: Nope, AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'items'

Comment: OK, so it is indeed a list. So you need to update what your desired output actually is. Do you want to join the keys and the values with a tab, and then join those pairs with a new line?

Comment: @Cory Madden  , yes it's exactly what i want

Comment: OK, I've updated my answer with an explanation of how you can join all the dicts in `sectionResults` before you use my first answer.

Comment: something wrong: ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)

Comment: Yea, sorry. Here's a better solution: `'\n'.join(str(x) + '\t' + str(y) for x, y in joined_dicts)` where joined_dicts is the dicts joined like so: `reduce(lambda p, v: p + v, [[t,y] for t, y in [z.items() for z in sectionResults]])`

Comment: I've once again updated my original answer with this solution. It works for me in the shell with a list of dicts, so I think it will work for you.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the sectionResults is like below.

```
sectionResults={'ones': '111', 'twos': '222', 'threes': '333', 'fours': '444'}
```

You need to package the inner and outer join's in lists.

```
print('\n'.join(['\t'.join([key, sectionResults[key]]) for key in sectionResults.keys()]))
```

This should give you the results like this.

```
fours   444
ones    111
twos    222
threes  333
```

## What was missing

1. `str.join` takes a list in one argument. The comprehension you had was missing the square brackets that make it proper list.
2. You are accessing the data in the dictionary using the `key`. This means you should iterate on `sectionResults.keys()` instead of `sectionResults` which normally returns a `(key, value)` tuple.

Comment: there is wrong: '  TabError: inconsistent use of tabs and spaces in indentation  '   , and I don't understand how fix it

Comment: This is probably due to missing tabs in the code itself. Are you using the joined string to generate python code and run it later?

Comment: i am writing this string to .html

Comment: The tab indentation error is usually associated with having a code sentence that is not inline with the tabs of previous/next sentences. The only way to know is a sentence is in a loop, for example, is to have it indented. 

Now the problem is, you pasted few lines of code into a bigger code and did not match the indentation. It depends on your editor if it uses '\t' indentation or just 4 spaces. My guess is your editor uses spaces and you probably missed a space or two during paste.

Comment: oh, sorry, not that mistake copied, there is: ' AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'keys' '

Comment: This means that sectionResults "is not the dictionary you think it is" as  Blckknght pointed out. From this error, it appears to be a list. Print it out and check its structure. I am guessing it is an array of tuples.